# How to calculate velocity.x to jump between platforms?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have 3 platforms and a player that needs to jump from one platform to the exact center of the next platform to the right/left. Right now I'm using physics on the platforms and player, and adding velocity.y for the jump strength, and I would like to calculate the velocity.x calculated by the centers of the current platform he's on, and the next platform he should jump to.

Does anyone have an idea on how to implement this calculation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the next platform *is at the same height* and that gravity only points downward (i.e. gravity has a zero X component), you can use the following formula:

```
velocityX = distance * gravity * 0.5 / velocityY
```

Where `distance` is the distance you want to cover (distance between platforms), `gravity` is the *absolute* value of  gravitational acceleration (`9.81` in Unity by default) and `velocityY` is the vertical velocity component of the player after applying the jump force/impulse (velocity).

If the platforms are *not* level, that'll require some more calculations.

Comment: so if I perform a jump by adding force of -350 to the velocity.y, it should divide by -350? ans I assume distance is in units?

Comment: No, it should be divided by the final velocity, that is the velocity *after* you have added `-350`. Not sure how you got that large a value, and that too negative. And yes, distance is in units.